# [AWS][Azure][Multi-Cloud] Regarding multi cloud resource access using sdk's

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, azure, cloud

Currently , we have our infra on AWS, and we use stack which consist S3, SNS, SQS, etc. So recently we are planning to move to Azure, to use corresponding infea like Blobstorage etc.
Is there is any library, which can be included in project to  decide at runtime whether call is for Azure or AWS. and based on request, it will do operation on corresponding cloud service provider. No proxy is required like S3 proxy etc Eg:

```
Http Call --> My company Service ->{some thirdparty library}--->|------->AWS
                                   {to decide at runtime}       |
                                                                |------->Azure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Apache Libcloud](http://libcloud.apache.org/) may satisfy your needs, but which be for Python, not Java. You can try to use it via [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) on Java Platform.

Comment: This is great. Is there is any other library, in pure java. Any idea. Thanks

Comment: @Chandra Just as I known, there is not any other library in pure java. Otherwise, I will directly tell you.